# Can I add a DependencyProperty on an windows user control?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-4.0, user-controls

I'm trying to host a Visio ActiveX object in a WPF application.

To do this, I created a Windows user control project where I add the Visio object. This windows user control is then hosted on an WPF user control in an WindowsFormsHost object.

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfHost" Grid.Row="1">
    <wf:VisioUserControl FileNamePath="?"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

What I would like to do is to bind the value of the *FileNamePath* member to the value of a *TextBox* element which defines the path.

The project follows the MVVM pattern, so there is no way that I can access the *VisioUserControl* object in my ViewModel.

The solution I was thinking about is to bind the *FileNamePath* member to the value of the *TextBox* that contains the path, but it is not a *DependencyProperty* and it seems that I'm not able to define one in the code behind of the windows user control.

So, is there any workaround to perform this binding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask what the windows user control layer is for? Why not just create a `WPFUsercontrol` with the `WindowsFormsHost` in it, and in the code behind attach the `VisioActiveX` `Object` as the `WindowsFormsHost`'s child? then you can put the `DependencyProperty` in the `WPFUserControl`. Seeing as its a standalone usercontrol you can pretty much use the code behind without worrying. Its very coupled to the `Visio ActiveX` object anyway....

Comment: I've added the windows user control project for reusability purposes, although I do no re-use it in any other place..

Comment: You mean to reuse in other `Winforms` applications? That's fine and all but for the purposes here you seem to just need a `WPF` `UserControl`. What I would do is a `WPF Application` with the attached property to bind to, which is then placed in the `ActiveX` `Object`, and then wrap this object in another `Windows User Control` when you need to use it in `WinForms`. I mean give me a link where I can get this object and I'll host it for you in a user control if you like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a `UserControl` that wraps your `VisioUserControl` (I wrote a [simple tutorial on UserControl creation here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/)). You can then add a `FileNamePath` dependency property to your `UserControl`. In the property changed handler of this dependency property, set the `FileNamePath` property on the `VisioUserControl` that this user control wraps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going through the article right now :)

Comment: Updated link here... http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have created an example of a WPF usercontrol that is hosting a Winforms control, with a dependency property that is bound to the winforms control's text property.

```
 public partial class ActiveXObjectHoster : UserControl
{
    private static System.Windows.Forms.Label testObject;
    public ActiveXObjectHoster()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testObject = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        windowsFormsHost1.Child = testObject;
    }

    #region Properties
    public static DependencyProperty FileNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FileName", typeof(string), typeof(ActiveXObjectHoster), new UIPropertyMetadata("",new PropertyChangedCallback(OnFileNamePropertyChanged)));


    public string FileName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FileNameProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FileNameProperty, value);
        }
    }


    private static void OnFileNamePropertyChanged(
DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        testObject.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
    }


    #endregion
}
```

---

Here is the xaml of the control (its very simple)

```
<UserControl xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"  
         x:Class="WPFTestApp2.Controls.ActiveXObjectHoster"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Name="ObjectHost"
         Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid>
           <my:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="windowsFormsHost1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

What you need to do is change the test object from a Label to whatever Visio object you were using. Then in the property callback change the text property to the filename or whatever property you wanted.

As mentioned above this is done in the code behind, but that *is fine* for a user control, its completely decoupled from whatever thing is using it, you just need to bind to the filename property of the control.

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9JOiSJxT9vjZDJjZmU2MTAtMDI1OC00YzhlLWI0OGMtYTdjMzZlNWJmODQz) to a project I created showing how the control is used. There is a textbox whos text is bound to the FileName property, which changes the Winforms Labels text.

You can place this in a Winforms Usercontrol if you want to use it in winforms (like you mentioned in your reply to my comment)

Try replacing the label for your control and see if it works.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but I implemented just that following ColinE's tutorial.
I used this code though to bind my variable to the value in the textbox, instead of using a code behind handler (which btw in your solution it's located in the wrong class file)
`<uc:VisioControl Grid.Row="1" VisioFileName="{Binding ElementName=tbFullFileName,Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`

Comment: @AdrianArsene sorry I'm confused about my mistake ^_^, I assume you created that VisioControl as a UserControl to house the Winforms Visio ActiveX object? I'm binding to that one in my mainwindow (if you look at the link in my example that uses this code). I'd love to know what you mean.

Comment: @AdrianArsene the code behind is done in the control, to put the dependency property into the actual winforms control (cause I assume you can't bind to it's properties)

Comment: @AdrianArsene I'll take a look at his link and see if I can find what I did wrong : )

Comment: The `textbox_changed` event is in the class file of the user control, where you set the value of the `FileName` property, but the textbox itself is located in the `MainWindow.xaml`file.
It's a small error, it's not an issue. But I have already implemented ColinE's solution before I saw yours anyway..
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah i see. Heh I actually changed it after I copied that code. Ok cool thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement a UserControl to wrap the WindowsFormHost and the Visio user control? Then you cann add a Dependency Property, and implement in the code behind a handler for the PropertyChangedCallback, and appropiately interact with the WinForms control