# Alter hosted Winform control from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry to be cliche... but I'm pretty new to WPF and MVVM so I'm not sure how to handle this properly. I have a WinForms control within one of my views that I need to modify in it's code behind when an event is raised in the ViewModel. My view's datacontext is inherited so the viewmodel is not defined in the views constructor. How would I go about properly handling this? I am not using any frameworks with built in messengers or aggregators. My relevant code is below. I need to fire the ChangeUrl method from my ViewModel.

EDIT: Based on the suggestion from HighCore, I have updated my code. I am still not able to execute the ChangeUrl method however, the event is being raised in my ViewModel. What modifications need to be made??

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl ...>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <vlc:AxVLCPlugin2 x:Name="VlcPlayerObject" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl.cs

```
public partial class VlcPlayer : UserControl
{
    public VlcPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string VlcUrl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(VlcUrlProperty); }
        set
        {
            ChangeVlcUrl(value);
            SetValue(VlcUrlProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VlcUrlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("VlcUrl", typeof(string), typeof(VlcPlayer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void ChangeVlcUrl(string newUrl)
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

view.xaml

```
<wuc:VlcPlayer VlcUrl="{Binding Path=ScreenVlcUrl}" />
```

ViewModel

```
private string screenVlcUrl;
public string ScreenVlcUrl
{
    get { return screenVlcUrl; }
    set
    {
        screenVlcUrl = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ScreenVlcUrl");
    }
}
```

Comment: winforms doesn't support MVVM. you will have to keep a reference to the View from whatever place you need this done, or use an EventAggregator or something like that.

Comment: Otherwise put your winforms stuff inside a WPF `UserControl` and have some DependencyProperties in that UserControl and manipulate the winforms thing in the property change callbacks of those DPs.

Comment: @HighCore - Thanks for the suggestion. I have made the recommended changes however, it is still not functioning properly. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF does not execute your property setter when you Bind the property, instead you must define a Callback method in the DependencyProperty declaration:

```
public string VlcUrl
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(VlcUrlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(VlcUrlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VlcUrlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VlcUrl", typeof(string), typeof(VlcPlayer), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnVlcUrlChanged));

private static void OnVlcUrlChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var player = obj as VlcPlayer;
    if (obj == null)
       return;

    obj.ChangeVlcUrl(e.NewValue);
}

private void ChangeVlcUrl(string newUrl)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance, that did the trick! I had in the mean time found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391363/can-i-add-a-dependencyproperty-on-an-windows-user-control which was pointing me in the same direction. Thanks again!